# Responsive images scaling to screen width and keeping their ratio

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I'm building a (what I thought would be) a simple portfolio website.

[image]

As you can see from the attached upload, the images are displayed via absolute in different positions on the screen. However, when I resize the browser, the images get cut off. I've also tried using percentages, but then the spacing between the images changes when resizing the browser.

What I'm trying to achieve is to keep the ratio of the images, as well as the spacing between the images consistent on every screen device and height. Is this possible? How can I achieve it?

Comment: Use a container which has a relative position and a fluid width in which you put images in absolute position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it could be with the use of media queries.

I've made a very quick example of what I was meaning in the comment :

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfavc7sb/8/)

I use fluid width and absolute positionning to try to keep a proper ratio :

```
img { position: absolute;}
img:nth-child(1) { left: 0; top: 0; width: 40%;}
img:nth-child(2) {right: 10%; top: 10px; width: 40%;}
img:nth-child(3) {left: 0; top: 200px; width: 50%;}
img:nth-child(4) {right: 0; top: 200px; width: 40%;}

@media (min-width: 640px){
  img:nth-child(1) { left: 0; top: 0; width: 30%;}
  img:nth-child(2) {right: 10%; top: 10px; width: 30%;}
  img:nth-child(3) {left: 0; top: 200px; width: 40%;}
  img:nth-child(4) {right: 0; top: 200px; width: 30%;}
}
```

It's not fully functionnal and I've not made everything but I hope this way to do it could help you.